# Visual Studio 2005 + ASP.NET Web Application + Referencing Code

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005

I have inherited a code base that does not compile properly. The project is a Visual Studio 2005 web site. I want to move it to a web application. The first thing I am trying to do is move the "App_Code" directory over. The pages in the application rely on some class objects that are defined in the "App_Code" directory.

Visual Studio 2005 does not directly give you the ability to add a "App_Code" directory. Because of this, I manually created one. I then placed the class definitions in this directory. I then compiled the web application.

Next I attempted to migrate the Default.aspx page. This page derives from a class called GenericPage defined in the App_Code directory. However, I cannot seem to reference this class. The definition does not use any namespaces. Where does this code get stored? How do I reference it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this tutorial is helpful: [Walkthrough: Converting a Web Site Project to a Web Application Project in Visual Studio 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476%28VS.80%29.aspx)

I'm reading at various places that the App_Code folder should not be used in Web Application Projects. See also this SO question: [App_Code folder issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89570/appcode-folder-issues)

The solution given in that last link is:

> Create a new folder called code or
>   something and put them in there.

Answer (score 1):

More info here:
[Automatic reference of class files inside App_Code vs reference of class files outside App_Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336811/automatic-reference-of-class-files-inside-appcode-vs-reference-of-class-files-ou/1336849#1336849)

Answer (score 0):

You might have to try grabbing it by using the global namespace.

Example:

```
var somePage = new global::DefaultNamespaceForProject.PageICantFind();
```